# How to update my module's dev branch on Drupal.org

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

I have a module on Drupal.org and I only have a dev branch.  This is how I added my dev branch by tagging with 7.x-1.x-dev:

```
git commit -m 'Creating module'
git push origin 7.x-1.x
git tag 7.x-1.x-dev
git push --tags
```

Now I made some more changes and would like to have my dev branch updated with the latest code. I delete the tag and recreate the tag:

```
git tag -d 7.x-1.x-dev
git push origin :7.x-1.x-dev
git commit -m 'Adding new feature'
git push origin 7.x-1.x
git tag 7.x-1.x-dev
git push --tags
```

I did this and I don't see my files get updated on Drupal.org. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to deal with tags for the dev branch. Tags are only required for stable releases.

Since you have already added your dev branch you just have to add your files, commit them and push them, like this:

1. git add path/to/files
2. git commit -m "Commit message"
3. git push origin 7.x-1.x

Then you just wait for drupal.org to reroll a new dev version. It takes up to 12 hours to see a new dev version on the project page.

You should be able to see your commits though if you click the **View commits** link in the development sidebar block.